# Methodbase.Invoke on Loaded assembly method does not hit breakpoint

Tags: c#, reflection

My setup is like this:

I am writing a Test Adapter for visual studio, that invokes a console application, which loads a test assembly and executes test methods.

- The runner works fine, but now I need to be able to Debug tests.
- Both my runner and test assembly have their respective `.pdb` in the same location.
- When the test is launched under debug mode, I am able to see that symbols are loaded.

So, here is some code on what I have been upto:

```
//load the test assembly
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("path\to\testassembly")

//not actual code, but it is representative 
var method = assembly.GetTypes().SelectMany(type => type.GetMethods()).Where(info => info.Name=="foo");

//Create type instance
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(method.DeclaringType);
method.Invoke(instance, args)
```

With this, when I put a breakpoint in the method, `foo`, Visual studio indicates that symbols have been loaded, and the breakpoint is active. But it never hits it.

And to verify if the method was called, I put some `Console.Writeline`s, it does hit the method.

Any tips on how to make it hit the breakpoint?

Comment: Test failed.  Use the debugger to find out what actually gets executed or send it back to the developer.

Comment: @HansPassant - I suspected it, but the runner goes ahead and executes the test successfully, it just doesn't hit the breakpoint.

Answer (score 1):

put breakpoint on this line

```
method.Invoke(instance, args)
```

when hit, press F11

Comment: This isn't what I am after, the debugger attachment is a `feature` and the user need not know about this.